# ¿Porqué el metodo PUT no me guarda datos?

Tags: php, api, rest, slim

Estoy haciendo una RestFUL con SLim PHP y tengo el siguiente problema, cuando trato de editar o utilizar el método PUT, me envía los datos, pero cuando los voy a consultar me aparece vacio y si trato de volver a editar el mismo id me envía error, como si no existiera el registro, pero hago la consulta por un GET y si me aparece. Gracias

Este es el codigo

```
$app->put('/mascotas/:id', function($id) use($db, $app) {
$datosform = $app->request;
$consulta = $db->prepare("update mascotas set estado=:estado, creado_por=:creado_por, fecha_registro=:fecha_registro, nombre=:nombre, sexo=:sexo, edad=:edad, color=:color, pedigri=:pedigri, ranking=:ranking, descripcion=:descripcion, likes=:likes, pareja=:pareja, adoptar=:adoptar, vender=:vender, color_ficha=:color_ficha where id=:id");

$estado = $consulta->execute(
       array(
          ':id' => $id,
          ':estado' => $datosform->put('estado'),
          ':creado_por' => $datosform->put('creado_por'),
          ':fecha_registro' => $datosform->put('fecha_registro'),
          ':nombre' => $datosform->put('nombre'),
          ':sexo' => $datosform->put('sexo'),
          ':edad' => $datosform->put('edad'),
          ':color' => $datosform->put('color'),
          ':pedigri' => $datosform->put('pedigri'),
          ':ranking' => $datosform->put('ranking'),
          ':descripcion' => $datosform->put('descripcion'),
          ':likes' => $datosform->put('likes'),
          ':pareja' => $datosform->put('pareja'),
          ':adoptar' => $datosform->put('adoptar'),
          ':vender' => $datosform->put('vender'),
          ':color_ficha' => $datosform->put('color_ficha')
       )
);

if ($consulta->rowCount() == 1)
    echo json_encode(array('estado' => true, 'mensaje' => 'Datos de Mascota actualizados correctamente.'));
else
    echo json_encode(array('estado' => false, 'mensaje' => 'Error al actualizar datos, datos 
                    no modificados o registro no encontrado.'));
});
```

Acá esta el registro antes de hacer el PUT
[image: Registro antes de hacer el PUT]

Resalto que estoy haciendolo desde POSTMAN, lo que me emula el cliente que consume la rest.
Hago un formulario exactamente como los datos dentro del array del codigo para guardar los datos.

Me aparece el siguiente mensaje en POSTMAN:
{"estado":true,"mensaje":"Datos de Mascota actualizados correctamente."}

Luego voy a consultar nuevamente el registro, pero me aparece vacío excepto por el id

Finalmente voy a darle nuevamente a editar ese id y me dice:

{"estado":false,"mensaje":"Error al actualizar datos, datos no modificados o registro no encontrado."}

Comment: Te ha servido la respuesta? Han aparecido otros problemas?

Answer (score 1):

Para tomar los parámetros `$datosform->put('nombreVariable')` el PUT debes enviarlo con la opción "x-www-form-urlencoded".

Si no, los parámetros serán enviados dentro del cuerpo (`body`) del mensaje. En cuyo deberías poder obtenerlos mediante `$datosform->getParsedBody()`, si los datos XML o JSON. En otro caso, deberás parsear el `string` que vaya en el cuerpo del mensaje para obtener los valores de los parámetros.

Referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23761425/get-put-params-with-slim-php

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió mucho